# How to output only eigenvectors using Matlab eig function

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

I want to output only the eigenvectors in Matlab. Code used is

```
[evec,eval]=eig(A)
```

How to do?

I think Matlab is rescaling output. For example,

```
A=[-5 -2; -1 -4] has evec1=[1,1/2]=[2,1] and evec2=[1,1]
```

Is there a way to do this? I like to check what I do by hand.

Thanks, MM,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to ignore the eigenvalues returned from `eig`, do the following:

```
[evec, ~] = eig(A);
```

The columns of `evec` represent **normalized** eigenvectors of `A`. Simply normalize your hand calculated eigenvectors and then compare with `evec`.

Comment: Savithru, The output is` easy to read now. One of the things I have been working on is to put each column of the matrix of eigenvectors into its unique vector so I can normalize. 

%% Eigen Analysis
A
lambda = eig(A)
[evec, ~] = eig(A)

Rescale the entries of evec so it spans [0, 1]
m = min(x(:)); M = max(x(:));
x = (b-a) * (x-m)/(M-m) + a;

Comment: I just saw the new question you posted. You don't have to do anything to `evec`, it is already normalized. Normalized doesn't mean the entries have to be in [0,1]. It just means that the L2-norm (square-root of the sum of squares) of each column of `evec` is equal to 1.

Comment: I need to slow down and think.  I need to take the eigenvectors computed by hand and normalize them and compare to Matlab answers. Now I am thinking how to unscale Matlabs eigenvectors. Your comment was very helpful. MM